# Looking for creepy animated trailer with blue girl and the line "If you can't hide, dance!"

Tags: story-identification

Looking for creepy animated trailer with blue girl and the line "If you can't hide, dance!" I vaguely remember some kind of egg person. Could someone find it and provide a link?

Comment: sound like hazbin hotel